# find max and min of array c++ using recursion without changing function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need help trying to find the min and max values in an array recursively in c++. the functions were given and cannot be changed.

I tried it out for both but for some reason nothing happens and the code does not enter the loop and I want to know what I am doing wrong. Here is my main and the min and max functions.

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = { 46, 22, 7, 58, 91, 55, 31, 84, 12, 78 };

    if (findMax(array, 10) == 91)
    {
        cout << "findMax is correct!" << endl;
    }

    if (findMin(array, 10) == 7)
    {
        cout << "findMin is correct!" << endl;
    }

    int findMax(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i = (size - 1);
        int max = 0;
        if (array[0] < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
            findMax(array, size - 1);
        }
        return max;
        return 0;
    }

    int findMin(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = size - 1;
        if (i == j) 
        {
            return array[i];
            i++;
        }

        int temp = findMin(array, size);

        if (array[i] < temp) 
        {
            return array[i];
        }

        else 
        {
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say functions were given, do you mean the function prototypes? i.e. `int findMin(int array[], int size)` and `int findMax(int array[], int size)`?

Comment: `findMax(array, size - 1);` just ignores the return value?

Comment: I would recommend reducing the problem set to just {1}, then {1,2},  etc.  And incrementally fix your find functions.

Comment: I strongly recommend removing the `findMin` and `findMax` functions from `main`. Standard C++ does not support nested functions. Using them reduces the portability of your program.

Comment: Why don't you just use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Probably because this is a school assignment

Comment: @Rietty Maybe. The question doesn't say. In any case, I'd hope that schools teach students to use what's in `<algorithm>`. In real life, production code, rolling your own min/max element function(s) would just be plain stupid.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case, I often look over my college friends homework assignments or give pointers on debugging, and sadly they always have very stupid restrictions regarding them, such as must use this or must use that. (e.g. write your own stack even though `std::stack` exists for example.) Currently there is a disconnect between what is taught at school and what is actually needed in real life production code. And for most students this is only really realized when they first get into a job and start programming. On the point of the question not --

Comment: -- saying, I simply made an educated guess because they said `cannot modify the function` or similar. But alas, using `<algorithm>` or even most of the standard headers aren't taught in school.

Comment: @Rietty Alas, answering how to solve such mostly unuseful questions and restrictions for professionals might just attract more of such VLQ stuff.

Comment: Extra cruft on SO is annoying, but not nearly as annoying as working beside a programmer who cut-n-pasted their way into the job.

Comment: @user4581301 You pretty nail my PITAs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you simply go backwards, return the min of each pair of elements and then next level make array size one smaller. Example:

```
int findMin(int array[], int n) 
{ 
    // if size = 0 means whole array has been traversed 
    if (n == 1){
        return array[0]; 
    }
    return min(array[n-1], findMin(array, n-1)); 
}
```

And you can do the `findMax` using the same methodology.