# Find max value in a vector recursively in C++

Tags: c++

i am trying to wirte a function to find a the max value in a vector recursively. To do that i want to test in the findMax function if it can return the last value in the list right. But at the end, when the list has just one element, it returns me the adress of variable and not the value. Why is it?

```
/// finding max value in a list recursively
template <typename T>
int findMax(std::vector<T> arrayVector)
{
    if(arrayVector.size()==1)
    {
        return arrayVector[0];
    }

    int op1= arrayVector[0];
    std::vector<T> newVector (arrayVector.cbegin() + 1, arrayVector.cend());
    disPlay(newVector);
    int op2= findMax(newVector);

}


/// print vector
template <typename T>
void disPlay(std::vector<T> vectorArray)
{
    for (int i=0; i< vectorArray.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << vectorArray[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}



main()
{
    std::vector<int> arrayVector = {6, 8, 19, 20, 23, 41, 49, 53, 56};

    std::cout << findMax(arrayVector) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not all paths of `int findMax(std::vector<T> arrayVector)` return (leading to UB). Compiler might warn  you about that...

Comment: `findMax` does not return a value in all return paths.  Increase the warning level of your compiler and it will tell you this.

Comment: Hint: In addition to missing a return in your recursive function (and the return type on your `main()`), notice that you also never actually do any *work* in your recursive function. You take an item out of the vector and then whittle down the vector to call your recursive function again, but where is the actual logic where you find a maximum value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran you program and it triggered several warnings, the one that probably justifies the unwanted behaviour is the lack of return value in `int findMax(std::vector<T> arrayVector)`.

```
template <typename T>
int findMax(std::vector<T> arrayVector)
{
    if(arrayVector.size()==1)
    {
        return arrayVector[0];
    }

    int op1= arrayVector[0];
    std::vector<T> newVector (arrayVector.cbegin() + 1, arrayVector.cend());
    disPlay(newVector);
    int op2= findMax(newVector);
    return op2; //<-- added return
}
```

I corrected the problems in https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kts9qs7MooG4dEQL

It seems ok now.

Use compiler warnings, it can save you a lot of time an headaches.

Now, this solves the issues with your code, but I would advise the use of [**`std::max_element`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to get max values in a C++ data structure.

Here is a test sample of a function to get the max value recursively in an unordered vector witch loses the last element in each iteration:

```
template <typename T>
void findMax(std::vector<T>& arrayVector)
{
   if(arrayVector.size() == 0) //stop condition
       return;

   int max = *std::max_element(arrayVector.begin(), arrayVector.end());
   std::cout << "Max value: "<< max << std::endl;
   arrayVector.erase(arrayVector.end() - 1);  //last element being deleted in every recursion

   findMax(arrayVector);
}
```

Check it in https://wandbox.org/permlink/0oyGnXoQdwhl3kUJ

Comment: Except `op1` is still unused, and the result isn't necessarily the max value.

Comment: @FredLarson that's right, that's why I removed it from the code, it isn't needed, I addressed the problem, didn't really focused on refactoring an optimization.

Comment: It is needed if you want to find the max value rather than simply the last. With the OP's example, the vector is in order, so the last *is* the max. But I presume that isn't a given, or finding the max would be even easier!

Comment: @FredLarson, the question is "it returns me the adress of variable and not the value. Why is it?" That is what I tried to solve, wasn't expecting extra work but ok, I'll take a look at it as soon as I can put my daughter in bed :) GMT

Comment: 6 is still not displayed just 8 upwards. But if its ok for him  - I wont bother :)

Comment: @Ivanovic, well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is convoluted:

- it's not actually computing the max of the vector
- not all paths return a value
- you are copying `std::vector` objects around with no real purpose

STL has the advantage of abstracting iterators, which make your attempt rather trivial:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
T findMax(C begin, C end)
{
  if (begin+1 == end)
   return *begin;
  else
   return std::max(*begin, findMax<T,C>(begin+1, end));
}
```

**Mind: the code is not checking for correctness of input.**

Comment: If begin == end, you're causing undefined behavior.

Comment: [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) makes it even more trivial!

Comment: @Ayxan: of course it's UB, I'm just providing a simple example to the OP without any kind of bound checking. But I'll specify that just for future readers.

Comment: Why are you not providing a solution? (no offense)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
T findMax(const std::vector<T> vec, size_t index=0){

    if(index==vec.size()-1) return vec[vec.size()-1];
    return ( vec[index] > findMax(vec,index+1))?vec[index]:findMax(vec,index+1) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be a recursive solution without ol' `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> arrayVector = {6, 8, 19, 20, 23, 41, 49, 53, 56};

  const int max = std::accumulate(
                    arrayVector.cbegin(),
                    arrayVector.cend(),
                    std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                    [](int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }
                  );
  std::cout << max << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier solution by [Rietty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814998/7163942) to similar question and solutions in this thread follow vector from 0 to end. Next follows vector from end to 0 to simplify recursive function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T  findMax (vector<T> values, size_t end) {
  if (0 == end) return values[0];

  return max (findMax (values, end - 1), values[end]);
}

template<typename T>
T  inline findMax (vector<T> values) {
  return findMax (values, values.size() - 1);
}

int main () {
  vector<int> values = { 6, 8, 19, 20, 23, 41, 49, 53, 56 };

  cout << findMax (values) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple code:

```
int find_max(int a[], int length){
      if (length == 0) return a[length];
  
      return std::max(a[length-1], find_max(a, length-1));
 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include "iostream"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;
int maxre(vector<int> array);

int main()
{
    vector<int> data = {210, 800, 2,150 ,19,600};
    cout << maxre(data);
    return 0;
}

int maxre(vector<int> array)
{
    static int index = -1;
    
    if (array.size() == index + 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        index++;
        int current = array[index];
        int back = maxre(array);
        return current > back ? current : back;
    }
    return 0;
}
```